# Why have Apache commons-math based it's Fraction on int type?

Tags: java, cpu, rational-numbers, apache-commons-math

Why have Apache `commons-math3` based it's [`Fraction`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math//javadocs/api-3.1.1/org/apache/commons/math3/fraction/Fraction.html) on `int` type???

Are there any reasons to use `int` instead of `long`? Do we have some performance gains here? Aren't `long`s process at the same speed as `int`s on modern CPUs?

I think we got only unneeded limitations from this decision.

Please correct me if I am mistaking.

Comment: I would say a usable `Fraction` class should use `BigInteger`s. Even with `long`, you get overflow for fairly trivial computations.

Answer (score 4):

If you want arbitrary precision, use [`BigFraction`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math//javadocs/api-3.1.1/org/apache/commons/math3/fraction/BigFraction.html).  Many platforms -- especially e.g. Android -- have tight memory constraints and may not be as efficient for 64-bit computations.  Additionally, any performance improvements to `long` may not have been available when `Fraction` was originally written, and for API compatibility, it may not be changeable.

Comment: They made new package `math3` to break compatibility. Actually they have a number of incompatibilities with previous version. They could change `Fraction` to `long` also. Also I don't believe mobile devices were taken into account here...